# Material UI: Style nested components in TablePagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How do I style in the buttons with the `actions` panel of the `TablePagination` component?

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import MuiTablePagination from '@material-ui/core/TablePagination';

const styles = {
  root: {
    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)',
    backgroundColor: '#b1c4cd',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    fontSize: '14px',
    width: '100%'
  },
  actions: {
    button: {
      color: 'yellow' // not working
    },
    MuiButtonBase: {
      color: 'yellow' // not working
    }
};

export const StyledTablePagination = withStyles(styles)(MuiTablePagination);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add style to the IconButton itself :

```
const PaginationTheme = withStyles({
  actions:{
    color:'red'
  }
})(TablePagination);
```

Here's an example of all [red buttons](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-zmeok)

You can also use the class of the button to change it's style:

```
const PaginationTheme = withStyles({
  actions: {
    '& .MuiButtonBase-root:not([disabled])':{
      color: "red"
    }   
  }
})(TablePagination);
```

Comment: I'm not directly styling this component, I need to style it by passing the style object in the HOC as above.

Comment: That does indeed apply the colour on the root component of actions, but can you apply a style on the paginations buttons directly, that's my question.

Comment: You can change the class directly, if that's what you mean